# PowerBI Dax measure values as rows in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, daxstudio

I have a really confusing doubt in PowerBI.

[I have a sample data as attached and slicers for Emp Code and Date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihbaw.png)

firstly, I need to bucket the attendance of each employee. i.e., "below 2 " or "above 2" which is dynamic with the slicers. For this I have used the below measure which works fine.

```
Bucket =
var CountPerDate = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), ALLSELECTED('Table'[Date]))
var b = IF (CountPerDate > 2, "Above 2","Below 2")
RETURN b
```

[Now i need to create another table based on this bucket as Attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DTt3.png)
Both the bucket and % must be dynamic as it needed to change according to the slicers (Date&Emp code).
Can you guys please help me find a solution for the bucket & % table?

Comment: What's the Bucket % based on? Number of employees in each bucket in set date period - or - one employee's bucket across each defined period (week) over the set date period (eg month, year)

Comment: @SamNseir  date period is not considered for calculation. Bucket % is number of employees is each bucket by total employees.(eg :above-2 has 3 employees and below-2 has 2 employees then total employees will be 5 ,so bucket % for above will be 3/5*100 = 60% and for below-2 it will be 2/5*100 = 40%.
currently we dont need to include date info for any calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a new table for the bucket.

```
| Bucket  |
| ------- |
| Above 2 |
| Below 2 |
```

Either add it view PowerQuery or via DAX as a Calculated Table with:

```
Dim Bucket = DATATABLE("Bucket", STRING, { { "Above 2" }, { "Below 2" } })
```

Then you can create two Measures with the following:

```
Bucket Emp count = 
  IF(
    ISINSCOPE('Dim Bucket'[Bucket]),
    COUNTROWS( FILTER(VALUES('Table'[Emp Code]), [Bucket] = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim Bucket'[Bucket])) ),
    COUNTROWS( VALUES('Table'[Emp Code]) )
  )

Bucket Emp % = 
  DIVIDE(
    [Bucket Emp count],
    [Bucket Emp count]( REMOVEFILTERS('Dim Bucket'[Bucket]) )
  )
```

Then using the new table above (`Dim Bucket`), you can create a Table visual like this as an example:

[image]